# How do show conditional association in UML class diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I am using a UML class diagram to describe a gauge I've been asked to build for my employer. I am a mechE, and new to UML, but I am trying to develop disciplined habits. So far, this is what I have: [image: gauge class diagram]

My question concerns the Hardware class.  **I intend to show that a hardware class is can be comprised of only parts, only assemblies, or both parts and assemblies.**  My issue is that, as I look at this diagram, I think there exists a case where the hardware class can be comprised of no parts or assemblies.

Am I correct in this interpretation? Is there a way to describe an "or" condition to the classes comprising the hardware class? Or would I use a different diagram to describe this relationship?

Comment: If there are commonalities between `Part` and `Assembly`, you could have them extend from a common class, say `HardwarePart`, then `Hardware` could be comprised of `0..*` `HardwarePart`

Comment: Ok, so you're saying I might want to do something like say the `Hardware` class is comprised of `1..*` `HardwarePart` classes. And generalize that the `HardwarePart` class is made from `Part` or `Assembly` classes.  Is this correct?

Comment: Makes sense to me. Unless there is a large difference between `Part` and `Assembly`. From reading your diagram it looks like you are saying an `Assembly` is a collection of `Part` and `Hardware` is made of a combination of `Assembly` and/or `Part`, therefore it stands to reason that since `Hardware` is made of either, they can be abstracted to a `HardwarePart`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply overcome that by adding constraints to the connectors which tell that at least one must be non-zero.

[image]

Btw: look into the SysML profile. This is build especially for purposes like your case.